# download/scraping table from htmlTable

Tags: r, download

I am trying to download a csv from

https://oceanwatch.pifsc.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/goes-poes-1d-ghrsst-RAN.html

or I am trying to scrape data frame the html table output from the website found here

https://oceanwatch.pifsc.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/goes-poes-1d-ghrsst-RAN.htmlTable?analysed_sst[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-6.975):1:(42.025)][(179.025):1:(238.025)],analysis_error[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-6.975):1:(42.025)][(179.025):1:(238.025)],mask[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-6.975):1:(42.025)][(179.025):1:(238.025)],sea_ice_fraction[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-6.975):1:(42.025)][(179.025):1:(238.025)]

I have tried to scrape the data using

```
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("https://oceanwatch.pifsc.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/goes- 
  poes-1d-ghrsst-RAN.htmlTable?analysed_sst[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019- 
  02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-7):1:(42)][(179):1:(238)],analysis_error[(2019-02- 
  09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-7):1:(42)][(179):1: 
  (238)],mask[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-7):1:(42)] 
  [(179):1:(238)],sea_ice_fraction[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02- 
  09T12:00:00Z)][(-7):1:(42)][(179):1:(238)]")

test <-  url %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='table.erd.commonBGColor.nowrap') %>%
  html_text()
```

And I have tried to download a csv with

```
download.file(url, destfile = "~/Documents/test.csv", mode = 'wb')
```

But neither worked either. The download.file function downloaded a csv with the node description.  and the rvest method gave me a huge character string on my macbook and a null data frame on my windows.  I have also tried to use selectorgadget (chrome extension) to obtain only data i need, but selectorgadget does not seem to work on the htmlTable

Comment: The site allows you to download the data in a variety of formats - why not download it first and then read it into r?

Comment: I have to download files from the range of 2004-2017 on a daily interval... maybe even hourly.  So writing a loop that goes through the different downloads would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find workaround solution using htmltab package, not sure if it's optimal though, it's big data frame for a webpage, took a while to load in data frame. table[2] is for actual table, as there're 2 html tables in link you've given.

```
url1 <- "https://oceanwatch.pifsc.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/goes-poes-1d-ghrsst-RAN.htmlTable?analysed_sst[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-6.975):1:(42.025)][(179.025):1:(238.025)],analysis_error[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-6.975):1:(42.025)][(179.025):1:(238.025)],mask[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-6.975):1:(42.025)][(179.025):1:(238.025)],sea_ice_fraction[(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z):1:(2019-02-09T12:00:00Z)][(-6.975):1:(42.025)][(179.025):1:(238.025)]"
tbls <- htmltab(url1,which = "//table[2]")
rdf <- as.data.frame(tbls)
```

let me know if it helps.